# tensorflow sticks to "Creating CudaSolver handles for stream" without moving forward

Tags: tensorflow

tensorflow sticks to Creating CudaSolver handles for stream without moving forward for multiple hours when training the deep neural network.

```
tensorflow version:1.12
cuda version: 9.0
cudnn version: 7.3
```

---

```
2019-06-13 09:45:17.087403: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 AVX512F FMA
2019-06-13 09:45:18.568961: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1432] Found device 0 with properties:
name: Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB major: 6 minor: 0 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.3285
pciBusID: 0000:5a:00.0
totalMemory: 15.89GiB freeMemory: 15.60GiB
2019-06-13 09:45:18.569067: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1511] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2019-06-13 09:45:19.636474: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:982] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2019-06-13 09:45:19.636549: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:988]      0
2019-06-13 09:45:19.636578: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1001] 0:   N
2019-06-13 09:45:19.636958: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1115] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 15117 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB, pci bus id: 0000:5a:00.0, compute capability: 6.0)
2019-06-13 09:45:21.246683: I tensorflow/core/kernels/cuda_solvers.cc:159] Creating CudaSolver handles for stream 0x56140303bcf0
```

Answer (score 0):

It is that complex deep neural network with a large of dataset would take a long period of time to train.  After running a few hours, the model starts to update.